# multiple foreign key that is also primary key in schema builder( laravel )

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I have this schema builder (I omitted the class extension and the schema down part)

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cat', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('path_img');
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }
```

this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('campo', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('nome');
    });
}
```

and this:

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('campo_cat', function(Blueprint $table)
    {

        $table->timestamps();

        $table->bigInteger('id_campo')->unsigned();
        $table->bigInteger('id_cat')->unsigned();
        $table->primary(array('id_campo','id_cat'));
        $table->foreign(array('id_campo','id_cat'))->references(array('id','id'))->on(array('campo','cat'));

    });
}
```

What I am trying to do is to state that the table 'campo_cat' has 2 entries that are BOTH primary key and are also foreign key, referenced to cat id and campo id.

1)If I use unsigned when I migrate  I get an array to string conversion error exception 
2)Is unsigned needed? or I can just define:

```
$table->unsigned('..');
```

as both 1) and 2) campo_cat doesn't create

The problem seems to be related to:

```
$table->foreign(array('id_campo','id_cat'))
->references(array('id','id'))
->on(array('campo','cat'));
```

EDIT:

I managed to make it work by doing:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('campo_cat', function(Blueprint $table)
    {

        $table->timestamps();

        $table->bigInteger('id_campo')->unsigned();
        $table->bigInteger('id_cat')->unsigned();
        $table->primary(array('id_campo','id_cat'));
        $table->foreign('id_campo')->references('id')->on('campo');
$table->foreign('id_cat')->references('id')->on('cat');

});
}
```

AND add

```
->unsigned(); //to the primary key in the other 2 scheme
```

Still wonder why if i use array it throws an error.

Comment: Have you tried `$table->bigIncrements('id')->unsigned();` on your cat and campo tables?

Comment: bigIncrement is not already unsigned, i mean unsigned is needed to pair a increment with an integer?

Comment: I've noticed in the past trying to setup foreign keys that the two fields must be EXACTLY alike. The slightest difference, even being signed vs unsigned, can cause it to fail. It's worth a try.

Comment: I've tried but still the same error, but i wonder why the error is array to string error.

Comment: hey, thank you, I have defined every foreign key singulary and then I unsigned everything.