# Will Eloquent automatically add this foreign key to the primary key's index?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Let's say I have a parent and a child table, in Laravel, for table `Order`, my model would look like this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('orders', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->integer('customer_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('customer_id')->references('id')->on('customers')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->increments('id');
```

I know Eloquent would consider `id` to be the primary key of `orders`, so an index would be automatically created on that primary key.

What should I do to make sure that `customer_id` is part of the primary key's index, setup in that order:

```
1.  customer_id
2.  id
```

Example of tables

```
      Customer
    +-------------+
    | id          | --> primary key
    |- - - - - - -|
    | name        |
    | address     |
    +-------------+
           |
           |
           |
           A
      Order     
    +------------------+        
    | customer_id (fk) | --- primary key
    | id               | --- primary key        
    |- - - - - - - - - |
    | date             |
    +------------------+
```

Comment: Try to add `$table->primary(array('id', 'customer_id'));` !

Comment: Refer below link. I hope it will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22477726/multiple-foreign-key-that-is-also-primary-key-in-schema-builder-laravel

Comment: Is there a reason why you need it as part of the primary key's index?  This isn't making a lot of sense to me.  If you are just looking for efficient joins, the foreign key should be enough and you can verify it by doing an `explain select...`

Comment: My idea is that it would be faster for MySQL to access `orders` through the primary key index (customer_id, id) when I query the order table with `customer_id`, since `customer_id` would be the first column of the primary key index. I've worked on DB2 and it was done that way, but i'm guessing MySQL does it differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to try this out and see what happens.

Starting with the customers table, I ran this statement...

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255),
    created_at DATETIME,
    updated_at DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I then created the following...

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    customer_id INT(11) UNSIGNED,
    created_at DATETIME,
    updated_at DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, customer_id)
);
```

Note here if you use `PRIMARY KEY (customer_id, id)`, it will result in a SQL error.  This makes me believe the DB2 functionality you are trying to replicate will not work exactly the same on MySQL and we actually need a foreign key.

Then after filling these tables with test data, I ran the following...

```
EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM customers
INNER JOIN orders ON customers.id = orders.customer_id;
```

This results in

```
+------+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | TABLE     | TYPE | possible_keys | KEY  | key_len | ref  | ROWS   | Extra                                           |
+------+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | customers | ALL  | PRIMARY       | NULL | NULL    | NULL |      4 |                                                 |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | orders    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 262402 | USING WHERE; USING JOIN buffer (flat, BNL JOIN) |
+------+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

I then added the foreign key...

```
ALTER TABLE orders ADD FOREIGN KEY customer_id (customer_id) REFERENCES customers (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

And running the same exact explain query before with the same exact data, I now get the results...

```
+------+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+-----------------------+-------+-------+
| id   | select_type | TABLE     | TYPE | possible_keys | KEY         | key_len | ref                   | ROWS  | Extra |
+------+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+-----------------------+-------+-------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | customers | ALL  | PRIMARY       | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                  |     4 |       |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | orders    | ref  | customer_id   | customer_id | 4       | cookbook.customers.id | 43751 |       |
+------+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+-----------------------+-------+-------+
```

As you can see, much fewer rows are being evaluated when I add the foreign key which is exactly what we are looking for.  Surprising for me probably because I'm not a DBA, running the following produces the same results...

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM orders WHERE customer_id = 4;
```

Even in this case, the composite primary key isn't doing anything for you however the foreign key is helping immensely.

With all that said, I think it's safe to forego the composite primary key and just set the `id` up as primary and set the `customer_id` up as a foreign key.  This also gives you the benefit of being able to cascade deletes and updates.

Comment: Wow, what a great explanation. Will definitely do as you suggested: `set the id up as primary and set the customer_id up as a foreign key` Thanks so much @user3158900

Answer (score 2):

> Will Eloquent automatically add this foreign key to the primary key's index?

Well, not automatic but its very easy.

To specify custom primary key, you can call `primary()` method from Blueprint class, called through $table. ie $table->primary().

For a single primary key, it accepts a string specifying the name of column to be made primary.

For composite key, you can pass an array of strings of the columns to be made primary. In your case

`$table->primary(
    ['id', 'customer_id']
)`

Comment: I've tried `$table->primary(['id', 'customer_id']);` and it works, but what I wanted was `$table->primary(['customer_id', 'id']);` since it would be faster for the index to find the orders when I query with `customer_id`, but Eloquent doesn't let me. I get the following message:  `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1068 Multiple primary key defined`

Comment: Thanks for you help @SirjanSharma, I didn't know about $table->primary()

Comment: You're welcome, glad i could help. (If the answer helps you vote it up, If the answer is what you looking for mark it as correct answer Correct Answer)